# How to filter out illegal json in ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a web server 1 to access a web server 2 endpoint.

Web server 1 has many  ajax calls. One is to access endpoint of web server 2 'https://webserver2.com/getresults':

```
  var deferCallReturn = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    crossDomain : true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://webserver2.com/getresults'
  });

  deferCallReturn.done(function(data) {
    // Process result. 
  })
  .fail(function(data) {
    // Process error. 
  });
```

The web server 2 endpoint result has 2 lines. Line 1 is illegal json, which I can't change.

```
  )]}'
  {"result": ["1", "2"]}
```

This result caused fail function to be fired.

My question is

1) how to remove the 1st line of illegal json, so that success function is called?

2) I tried ajaxSetup, but not able to get any result in 'data' parameter. Is this way to solve it? My understanding is all ajax call results are process by dataFilter, but, only 1 ajax call has this problem. How to deal with only this one call?

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
    dataFilter: function(data, type) {

      if (type == 'jsonp') {
        // Will remove 1st illegal json, and then return. But, not getting anything here? When getting here, data=undefined.     
        // return data;

      } else {
        return data;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Receive a string instead json with ajax, then remove the first line and finally convert to object with JSON.parse method.

Comment: It's always the wrong thing to try to make illegal markup or data "work".  Either fix the source, or use a different source.  You will have nothing but heartache trying to fix bad stuff.

Comment: elchininet, can you tell me how to do it? I changed:     contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8", But, 
failure function gets: { data = Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"}. dataFilter function: data=undefined. Same as   'contentType: application/json'. Not sure why, not getting anything.

Comment: I can not fix server 2 as developed not by me. Also, illegal json is by design for reason. Now, I don't event know if the server is really responding. The response I got from Chrome debugger is like: webserver2.com/getresults&callback=jQuery111102475197904277593_1450207817078&_=1450207817079. Also in debugger console "All" tab, I see error on left side: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ), and on right side show above link, if clicking, it show correct server 2 result (2 lines, 1st line is illegal json, 2nd line is legal json.

Comment: Does webserver 2 support CORS? I can see that you are currently using JSONP to make the cross domain AJAX call but this won't work with invalid JSON returned by the remote endpoint.

Comment: Hi Darin, I am not 100% CORS is supported, but why I am seeing the correct result in debugger. Can I parse out the invalid json, by using 'text/plain'?